# Is there an official wave for SO?

Tags: discussion

So now that everyone (well almost everyone) has their Google Wave invite where is the Offical SO Wave? Or does it already exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sign in to Wave.

20 minutes after the thing has finally loaded, enter this into the search box in the Inbox pane:

> with:public tags:stackoverflow

You should see one that's entitled, "[Any Stack Overflow users around here?](https://wave.google.com/wave/#restored:wave:googlewave.com!w%252BSsKz1PcYA)"

Is it official? No, but that's where the money is.

Comment: That wavelet is so long that it freezes when I view it. Or is it just me?

Comment: When a wave has over 100 blips, you can watch an entire episode of *Robot Chicken* before it fully loads.

Comment: As long as you are not over 500 blips, I wouldn't call it slow. Otherwise you were running out of adjectives describing slowness very fast....

Comment: YMMV depending on your browser and RAM available in your system too.

Comment: @John Smithers: so we are like Eskimos and snow then?